# mysql search by month and year as separate fields

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I want all sum of counts between these 2 month-year here month and year are 2 separate fields.

How can I do that ? Thanks for help.

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
JOIN
SELECT (SUM(`full_lead_count`)) AS `domainFullLeadCount`
FROM `abc`.`reports`
WHERE ((`month` >= 10)
       AND (`year` >= 2013))
  AND ((`month` <= 3)
       AND (`year` <= 2014)) LIMIT 1 bar ON val1 = val2
WHERE id = 123;
```

Comment: I want all sum of counts between these 2 month-year here month and year are 2 separate fields.                                      thanks for help.

Comment: Put question info in the question, not comments. You can edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These premises are definitely not ideal. If it is possible to change the database layout, then you should consider to use real [date datatypes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) from MySQL. Otherwise you could use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) in order to convert your two fields into a single DATETIME, which can then be handled more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as a comment rather than a useful answer...

Untested and very incomplete:

The issue is that if there was a range of year such as 2012 to 2014 then not all rows would be selected with the given example.

Something like the following will correctly select all the rows in the date range required:

```
SELECT (SUM(`full_lead_count`)) AS `domainFullLeadCount`
FROM `abc`.`reports`
WHERE ((`year` * 100 + `month`) >= 201310)
  and ((`year` * 100 + `month`) <= 201403)
```

And, yes it isn't nice as indexes cannot be used etc.